# Loadable/Unloadable django apps

Tags: django, plugins, pluggable

I wanted to make an application which could handle other applications as plugins, that the user could download and load/unload at any time. I read all the django documentation, and there doesn't seem to be a proper way to do it apart from installing the app by hand a doing a syncdb, with no possibility of unloading.

A good example of what I want to do could be the wordpress plugins. I wanted something like that for my django project, downloadable "plugins" that the user can load and unload at any time.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. Django loads all its `.py` files only once, when its *cgi process is started. So to updating your `urls.py` or `models.py` requires restarting cgi, and I don't think you want to allow your users doing this. :-)

Comment: I didn't think about that, you're right, that would mean to reload the wsgi process everytime a module is loaded. Thanks!